# Have to MPI_Iprobe several times before receiving messages

Tags: mpi, openmpi

The application I'm working on involves multiple processes all working on similar tasks, and only occasionally sharing information. I have a working implementation using openMPI, but I'm having issues with messages sometimes being received much later than they are sent.

At the moment, the main loop of each process begins by processing any waiting messages, then does a whole bunch of computation, then sends the results to each of the other processes using MPI_ISend. Something like:

```
while problem is unsolved:
  bool flag;
  MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
  while flag:
    MPI_Recv(&message, ...);
    // update local information based on message contents
    MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);

  result = doComputation(); // between 2s and 1m

  MPI_Request request;
  for dest in other_processes:
    MPI_Isend(result, ..., dest, &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); // Doesn't seem to make any difference
```

This works OK, but the following problem often occurs: Process X sends a message, but the next time Process Y probes, it finds no message. Often it is only one or two loops (and many seconds) later that Process Y gets the message sent by Process X. The messages always get through eventually, but Process Y shouldn't have to wait until the second or third time it probes to actually receive the message.

I don't have a solid understanding of how MPI works, but from reading other questions I think the problem has something to do with MPI not having a chance to progress the message, because in my program the MPI functions are only called very occasionally, rather than within a tight loop. Trying to give MPI some extra time to progress, I added a few dummy calls to Iprobe:

```
bool flag;
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
while flag:
  MPI_Recv(&message, ...);
  // update local information based on message contents
  MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ..., &flag, MPI_IGNORE_STATUS);
```

And it works - any sent messages are always received the very next time a process probes for them.

But this is ugly and I suspect it may give different results on different platforms. So is there an alternate way to allow MPI some time to complete message progression before probing? I don't want to use blocking receive without probing because Process Y should be able to continue computation when there are no messages waiting.

Thanks.

Comment: It works as advertised in the MPI standard. A single call to `MPI_Iprobe` is almost never enough. It is supposed to be used in busy-waiting loops. How many calls are needed for proper progression of the operations is very implementation-specific.

Comment: So is there any way of doing occasional message-checking within MPI?

Comment: The way is to use `MPI_Iprobe`. Just do not expect it to return true immediately and design your algorithm accordingly, e.g. do less computations when the loop did not process any message and also call the non-blocking probe function periodically inside the `doComputation` function in order to enable proper progression.